# What does this sentence mean from Sherlock Holmes?

Tags: meaning

> Leaning back in his arm-chair of an evening, he would close his eyes
>   and scrape carelessly at the fiddle which was thrown across his knee.

I think the scrape means play here, fiddle means violin. But the part 'which was thrown across his knee' confused me. 'which' is referred to the 'fiddle', right? so does that mean he threw the fiddle on his knee? thanks. If he was playing violin, how he put it on his knee; if he was not playing, then did the author merely mean he just scrape the violin?

Comment: Either he was holding it in his lap, sort of, or he was holding it like a cello.

Comment: *Scrape* means to play really badly (like a beginner). @HotLicks comment is apropos.

Comment: Here, 'thrown' = 'lying untidily'. [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/throw) sense 2.

Comment: that's why I confused. If he was playing violin, how he put it on his knee; if he was not playing, then did the author merely mean he just scrape the violin?

Answer (score 5):

[image: Holmes seated playing a fiddle]

This is the pic which is most suitable for that description

Comment: You should cite the source of the image.

Comment: I think you need to push the bottom of the fiddle against something to keep it steady, unless you pluck rather than bow. Not an expert though.

Answer (score 3):

The violin (a.k.a.fiddle) is held under the chin to play it properly, but there is nothing to stop anyone scraping the strings of the violin with the bow in any position whatsoever. The character of Sherlock Holmes was known to to "play" the violin in a careless manner while he was intoxicated, and this is why in the scene quoted, we find the character with the fiddle laid carelessly across his lap, scraping at the strings with the bow.

Comment: There is an old "country" style of playing a violin/fiddle in your lap.  I think I saw it done once, but it was maybe 50 years ago, so I can't give any details.

Comment: It's not uncommon to play it pressed against waist or hip rather than neck, although more often when standing.

Comment: Miles Hoffman, a musician and music commentator for NPR, told the story about asking a high-school audience in a southern state if anyone knew the difference between a violin and a fiddle. One student replied "A violin has strings and a fiddle has strangs."